# Is airside transit available at Tocumen airport, Panama?

Tags: transit, panama, pty, cuban-citizens, twov

My partner needs to transit in Panama on his way to meet me and my family in Barbados for a holiday.

He will be travelling Havana > Panama > Barbados with Copa Airlines on a single PNR. His connection time in Panama will be less than 3 hours on both outbound and return flights. All the information I’ve been able to find online states that he can TWOV for up to 9 hours providing he does not leave the international area of the airport. His luggage will be checked through to Barbados.

My question is:

- Does anyone know whether airside transit is available at Tocumen airport when transferring between Copa Airline flights?

I’ve tried emailing the airline but just got a standard response back directing me to travel document information.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

PTY is an extremely simple airport for transit. There's no separation of departing and arriving passengers, so you literally go directly from your arrival gate to your departure gate. As long as you don't go downstairs to immigration you won't even see them. Just get off the first plane, check a departure board for your gate number, and go directly to it.

I should also note that at the time of writing the new Terminal 2 is partly open. There is an airside walkway (complete with PTY's first moving walkways) between the terminals, and all the gates in both terminals have been renumbered. So check the signs, even if you've been there before.